# kotlin multiplatform library simple http get request test

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

I am new to kotlin multiplatform library.
I wanted to make a simple HTTP get request and test if it works.
here is what I have so far.
this is in the commonMain package

```
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*

object HttpCall {
    private val client: HttpClient = HttpClient()
    suspend fun request(url: String): String = client.get(url)
}
```

and here is my attempt to test

```
@Test
    fun should_make_http_call() {

        GlobalScope.launch {
            val response = HttpCall.request("https://stackoverflow.com/")
            println("Response: ->$response")
            assertTrue { response.contains("Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn") }
            assertTrue { response.contains("text that does not exist on stackoverflow") }
        }
```

Now, this should fail because of the second assert but it doesn't.
no matter what I do the test always passes.
and printing the response does not work either
what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test function will run in a single thread, and if the function ends without failing, the test passes. `GlobalScope.launch` starts an operation in a different thread. The main test thread will finish before the network calls get a chance to run.

You *should* be calling this with something like `runBlocking`, but testing coroutines in general, and ktor specifically, on Kotlin native, is not easy because there's no easy way to have the suspended function continue on your current thread.

Comment: Thanks.I get it now

Answer (score 0):

I will not use the `GlobalScope` or the `runBlocking` because they are not really made for Unit Test. Instead, I will use `runTest`.

Here are the steps:

- Check your `build.gradle` and make sure you do have under `commontTest` the lib 'kotlinx-coroutines-test' set

```
val commonTest by getting {
   dependencies {
      implementation(kotlin("test"))
      implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:${Version.kotlinCoroutines}")
      ...
   }
}
```

- Then into your directory `commonTest`, create a file and run

```
@Test
fun should_make_http_call() = runTest {
   val response = HttpCall.request("https://stackoverflow.com/")
   println("Response: ->$response")
   assertTrue { response.contains("Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn") }
   assertTrue { response.contains("text that does not exist on stackoverflow") }
}
```

Extra:
`runTest` does not handle exceptions very well, so if you are interested in making to catch any exceptions if happens. Change `runTest` for `runReliableTest`, You can get the code from this link https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1205#issuecomment-1238261240